# Passagem por referência, e salvando dados de um arquivo em um vetor

Tags: c, array, arquivo, struct, passagem-por-referência

estou com problemas em salvar os dados lido de um arquivo de texto e um vetor de uma estrutura que criei.

O meu objetivo é abrir um arquivo de texto, pegar os dados que estão salvos nele, e guardar em um vetor do tipo INFO. O meu programa compila perfeitamente, porém quando coloco para imprimir os dados de cada posição do vetor, todos os campos, menos matrícula e salário, estão vazios.

Eu tentei enviar o endereço do vetor `salvaDados(&pessoa)` mas isso também deu errado.

Então, peço gentilmente, que alguém me mostre como faço para gravar permanentemente os dados no meu vetor.
Obrigado =)

```
void salvaDados(INFO pessoa[]) {

   FILE* f;
   char linha[200];


  f = fopen("teste.txt", "r");

   if(f == NULL){
      printf("Desculpa, banco de dados indisponível\n");
      exit(0);
  }


    // O fseek faz com que a barra se seleção pule para local indicado;
   //Nesses caso, a barra irá pular 49 bytes a partir da linha inicial(SEEK_SET);    

   fseek(f, 49, SEEK_SET);

   int i = 0;
   while((fscanf(f,"%s", linha)) != EOF) {

      char* tok;
      tok = strtok(linha, ",");

      while(tok != NULL) {

         sscanf(tok, "%d", &(pessoa[i].matricula));
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");

        pessoa[i].nome = tok;
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
         pessoa[i].sobrenome = tok;
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
         pessoa[i].email = tok;
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
         pessoa[i].telefone = tok;
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");

         sscanf(tok, "%f", &(pessoa[i].salario));
         tok = strtok(NULL, ",");

      }

    i++;

  }


}
```

A minha struct foi definida da seguinte forma:

```
typedef struct informacoes{

  int matricula;
  char* nome;
  char* sobrenome;
  char* email;
  char* telefone;
  float salario;

}INFO;
```

Comment: No caso, se você ler sem esse NULL não vai funcionar? tenta passar para struct com as variaveis auxiliares. Tenta aí pra ver se dar certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa lembrar que o array *linha* é local e que a função *strtok* retorna um ponteiro para alguma posição desse array, sendo assim, você não pode simplesmente copiar esse endereço para a sua estrutura, pois os dados nesse array serão sobreescritos na próxima iteração (invalidando os dados anteriores) e o espaço de memória onde *linha* está alocado será liberado quando a função terminar.

A solução seria alocar um espaço para cada campo (nome, sobrenome, email e telefone) e usar a função *strcpy* para passar os valores para esses campos.